# How to dynamically change displayed content(with state) without violating reacts hookuse rules?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, jsx

I am implementing the client side for a tic-tac-toe web game.

I have 2 typescript files:

- TicTacToe.tsx: Main display, contains a switch statement, that depending on state displays the input or the game screen.
- TicTacTieAPI.tsx: Game screen + backend; if called establishes a websocket connection and initializes the client-side game state.

When testing I get the following error:

> TicTacToeAPI.tsx:5 Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by TicTacToe. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed. For more information, read the Rules of Hooks: https://reactjs.org/link/rules-of-hooks

|  | Previous render | Next render |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | useState | useState |
| 2. | useState | useState |
| 3. | useState | useState |
| 4. | useState | useRef |

I'm not sure what the standard way to resolve this issue is.

Here are the files:

TicTacToe.tsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import TicTacToeAPI from "./TicTacToeAPI";

export default function TicTacToe() {
  const [menuState, setMenuState] = useState("login");

  const [nickname, setNickname] = useState("");
  const [roomNumber, setRoomNumber] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div className="TicTacToe">
      <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
      {(() => {
        switch (menuState) {
          case "login":
            return input(setMenuState, setNickname, setRoomNumber);
          case "game":
            return game(setMenuState, roomNumber, nickname);
          case "end":
            return end();
          default:
            return null;
        }
      })()}
    </div>
  );
}

function game(
  setMenuState: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>,
  roomNumber: number,
  nickname: string
) {
  return (
    <>
      <div id="metaData">
        <p>Room number: {roomNumber}</p>
        <p>Nickname: {nickname}</p>
      </div>
      {TicTacToeAPI(nickname, roomNumber)}
      <div id="abandonButton">
        <button onClick={() => setMenuState("login")}>rage quit</button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

function end() {
  return <p>Game ended</p>;
}

function input(
  setMenuState: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>,
  setNickname: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>,
  setRoomNumber: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number>>
) {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    nickname: "genericName",
    roomNumber: 420,
  });

  const handleInputChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.id]: e.target.value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // validate input
    if (!formData.nickname || !formData.roomNumber) {
      alert("Please enter a nickname and room number");
      return;
    }
    // set parameters
    setNickname(formData.nickname);
    setRoomNumber(formData.roomNumber);
    // change menu state
    setMenuState("game");
  };

  return (
    <div id="playerInfoInput">
      <form className="playerInfo" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <h3>Nickname</h3>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="nickname"
          value={formData.nickname}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
        <br />
        <h3>Room number</h3>
        <input
          type="number"
          id="roomNumber"
          value={formData.roomNumber}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

TicTacToeAPI.tsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

export default function TicTacToeAPI(nickname: string, roomNumber: number) {
  //websocket
  const wsRef = useRef(new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/ticTacToe"));

  //set other data
  const [authToken, setAuthToken] = useState("");
(...)
  //websocket
  useEffect(() => {
    //configure message handler
    wsRef.current.onmessage = (message) => {
      handleMessage(message, stateData);
    };

    // Cleanup WebSocket connection when the component unmounts
    return () => {
      wsRef.current.close();
    };
  }, []);

  return (<p>board</p>)
}
```

According to my research since the hooks are in their own function components so this switching shouldn't be an issue, but apparently I have misunderstood something.

Comment: I think the issue might be inside the methods `input`, `game`, etc. that you are using inside the switch statement in **TicTacToe.tsx**.
If these methods are components (with hooks used in them), check if rendering them as components `<Input />` and `<Game />` fixes the issue. (Notice the capital first letters in component names)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm surprised you are not getting the React hooks error that hooks are being called from nested functions. None of `TicTacToeAPI`, `input`, or `game` are valid React function components.

Update the code such that these functions are valid React components and that they are rendered as JSX instead of being directly invoked. React function components take a single props object, the various props can be destructured from it.

Example:

TicTacTieAPI.tsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

interface TicTacToeApiProps {
  nickname: string;
  roomNumber: number;
};

export default function TicTacToeAPI({ nickname, roomNumber }: TicTacToeApiProps) {
  //websocket
  const wsRef = useRef(new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/ticTacToe"));

  //set other data
  const [authToken, setAuthToken] = useState("");
(...)
  //websocket
  useEffect(() => {
    //configure message handler
    wsRef.current.onmessage = (message) => {
      handleMessage(message, stateData);
    };

    // Cleanup WebSocket connection when the component unmounts
    return () => {
      wsRef.current.close();
    };
  }, []);

  return (<p>board</p>)
}
```

TicTacToe.tsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import TicTacToeAPI from "./TicTacToeAPI";
```

```
interface GameProps {
  setMenuState: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>;
  roomNumber: number;
  nickname: string;
}

function Game({ setMenuState, roomNumber, nickname }: GameProps) {
  return (
    <>
      <div id="metaData">
        <p>Room number: {roomNumber}</p>
        <p>Nickname: {nickname}</p>
      </div>
      <TicTacToeAPI nickname={nickname} roomNumber={roomNumber} /> // <-- JSX!
      <div id="abandonButton">
        <button onClick={() => setMenuState("login")}>rage quit</button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

```
function End() {
  return <p>Game ended</p>;
}
```

```
interface InputProps {
  setMenuState: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>;
  setNickname: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>;
  setRoomNumber: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number>>;
}

function Input({ setMenuState, setNickname, setRoomNumber }: InputProps) {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    nickname: "genericName",
    roomNumber: 420,
  });

  const handleInputChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.id]: e.target.value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // validate input
    if (!formData.nickname || !formData.roomNumber) {
      alert("Please enter a nickname and room number");
      return;
    }
    // set parameters
    setNickname(formData.nickname);
    setRoomNumber(formData.roomNumber);
    // change menu state
    setMenuState("game");
  };

  return (
    <div id="playerInfoInput">
      <form className="playerInfo" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <h3>Nickname</h3>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="nickname"
          value={formData.nickname}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
        <br />
        <h3>Room number</h3>
        <input
          type="number"
          id="roomNumber"
          value={formData.roomNumber}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
export default function TicTacToe() {
  const [menuState, setMenuState] = useState("login");

  const [nickname, setNickname] = useState("");
  const [roomNumber, setRoomNumber] = useState(0);

  const renderUi = () => {
    switch (menuState) {
      case "login":
        return (
          <Input
            setMenuState={setMenuState}
            setNickname={setNickname}
            setRoomNumber={setRoomNumber}
          />
        );

      case "game":
        return <Game {...{ setMenuState, roomNumber, nickname }} />;

      case "end":
        return <End />;

      default:
        return null;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="TicTacToe">
      <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
      {renderUi()}
    </div>
  );
}
```